# Prettier not converting end of line (eol) from CRLF to LF when formatting in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I have the prettier extension installed to the last version (9.5) and the configuration for the end of line (eol) is set to LF (default).

[image: Prettier eol configuration in vscode]

I would expect the eol for my files to be automatically set to LF when formatting a file.

But, in the case of CRLF files they remain set to CRLF even after formatting
(shift + alt + f in vscode on windows, or when I save the file since I have the "format on save" setting enabled) .
[image: File remains to CRLF]

Prettier is of course enabled in my settings.json for all the different file extensions I use

[image: Settings.json]

Am I doing something wrong ?

Thank you!

Comment: This seems to be a bug. There is an open issue for it: https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/1327